# Ansible hangs after parsing inventory

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible locally to configure my own machine and today (I haven't run the playbooks in a while) it all of a sudden started just hanging. I can't seem to run any playbooks at all, at least not locally. I'm at a new workplace and don't have any remote host handy to test on.

I'm using Ansible `2.7.1`, running on a stripped down Ubuntu `18.04`.

`ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
inventory=inventory
```

`inventory`:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

`test` (playbook):

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I'm alive"
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -vvvv test
ansible-playbook 2.7.1
  config file = /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/tjarvstrand/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) [GCC 7.3.0]
Using /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
/home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
Set default localhost to localhost
Parsed /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
```

After parsing the inventory, it's dead quiet. Please help

EDIT: I have also tested with `inventory`:

```
localhost ansible_connection=ssh
```

with the same result.

EDIT2:
`ansible -vvvv all -m ping` outputs:

```
ansible 2.7.1
  config file = /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/tjarvstrand/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) [GCC 7.3.0]
Using /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
/home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
Set default localhost to localhost
Parsed /home/tjarvstrand/playbooks/mini.iso/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.pyc
META: ran handlers
```

and then hangs

Comment: Could you try connecting to the local machine with SSH?

Comment: Did SSH connection produce any output that was different from local connection? What happens if you try command `ansible all -m ping`?

Comment: Yeah, the output was exactly the same when using ssh. Pinging hangs too. I've updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a user error. I have a local ssh wrapper that was messing things up. I still can't figure out why this causes problems even on a local connection though but at least now I can work around it.